# изменить отображение данных из массива json.Angularjs

Tags: json, angularjs

Здравствуйте , как можно изменить отображение данных которые приходят из json в такой вид:
Solt, Paper, Sugar.

В json приходят вида и отображаются ["Solt","Paper","Sugar"]

```
"roles": [
  "Solt",
  "Paper",
  "Sugar"
],
```

Таблица angular

```html
   <tr ng-repeat="cup in cups | filter:searchText">
    <td><img src="https://api.opendota.com{{cup.img}}" width="64" height="36"></td>
    <td ng-style="$index < 0 ? {'font-size' : '18pt'}: ''"> {{cup.localized_name}}</td>
    <td ng-style="$index < 0 ? {'font-size' : '18pt'}: ''">{{cup.primary_attr}}</td>
    <td ng-style="$index < 0 ? {'font-size' : '18pt'}: ''">{{cup.attack_type}}</td>
    <td ng-style="$index < 0 ? {'font-size' : '18pt'}: ''">{{cup.roles}}</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Посмотри тут.](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)
Решение:

```js
        var app = angular.module('app',[]);
        app.controller('TestController', TestController);

        function TestController(){
            this.data = { "roles": [
                                      "Solt",
                                      "Paper",
                                      "Sugar"
                                    ]};
            
          }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController as ctrl">

Задача: <div>{{ctrl.data.roles}}</div>
</br>
Решение: <div>{{ctrl.data.roles.join(', ')}}</div>

</body>
```